# I've trained an autopilot model using AutoML tool in Sagemaker. I want to load this model outside of sagemaker and score data in local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, automl, autopilot, autogluon

I have trained an aws autopilot model on Sagemaker. I am trying to load this model in local and score data. But I'm getting error when I'm trying to load model using pickle.

[image]

And when I'm trying to load model using autogluon, I'm getting error:

Can anyone please help me out how I can load autopilot model(trained using Sagemaker Automl UI interface) locally, outside aws and score data?

Comment: It depends on the algorithm of your best model. If its autogluon you should be able to deploy using the Autogluon container - https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/available_images.md#autogluon-inference-containers